# Static routes not being honored in my VirtualBox test lab

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I have been trying to set up a VirtualBox test lab with with two lightweight Debian virtual machines and a WanEM test system. All network adapters are host-only adapters (Internal would be ideal, but for some reason I can't get DHCP to work.) The initial topology looks like this:

> 192.168.56.101: Client #1
>
> 192.168.56.102: WanEM
>
> 192.168.56.103: Client #2

And everything works the way you would expect it to: all the machines can talk to each other and life is good.

I then do two things:

1. I add a static route on client #1: all traffic destined for client #2 will first go through the WanEM system
2. I add a rule in WanEM to add 1000ms of latency to all requests

After doing that, I immediately ran a traceroute on client #1, and everything is going through the WanEM system as designed. You can even see the 1000ms delay, which is great.

I then do a ping, and there is no delay. A subsequent traceroute shows that **traffic is no longer being routed through the WanEM system, despite the fact that route -n shows the route is still in use.** I would post a screenshot, but I have insufficient reputation here to do so.

I'm totally confused as to why this is happening. Is this a consequence of using a VirtualBox host-only adapter? Or is there something more fundamental that I'm not understanding?

Comment: What are the metrics of the routes involved?

Comment: Have you made sure icmp redirects are off on .102?  If not it will send a redirect to 101 telling to go straight to 103.

Comment: Paul, you were 100% correct -- ICMP redirects were the culprit. Thanks!